# Load multiple custom js files magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, requirejs

I am new to developer and want to implement blueprint3d library into my magento website https://github.com/furnishup/blueprint3d .
the html file requires 4 js files 'Three.js' Library and blueprint3d.js and some extra files for html propagation 
blueprint3d.js requires threejs library
examples.js requires blueprint3d.js and so on.

I tried to include them in the head section of the layout but don't work

```
 <head>
        <css src="AWstreams_RoomPlanner::css/example.css" />
        <script src="AWstreams_RoomPlanner::js/three.js" />
        <script src="AWstreams_RoomPlanner::js/blueprint.js" />
    </head>
```

I also tried to use requireJs but i can't understand how it's work and i can't implement it

```
   var config = {
    paths : {
        THREE: "AWstreams_RoomPlanner/js/three.js",
        BP3D: "AWstreams_RoomPlanner/js/blueprint3d"
    },
    shim: {
        'BP3D' : ['jquery']
    }
};
```

How can i go through that

Answer (score 0):

Hi below code will help you, i tried its working fine. And do not include .js in require js, just mention the file name. 
for ex: if file name is example.min.js then in require js you need to mention only example.min.

var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            cursor: 'Siemens_Hologram/js/jqplot.cursor',
            dragable: 'Siemens_Hologram/js/jqplot.dragable'
        }
    }
};